# <title> tags in IE9 not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Ok I have a strange issue again with Internet Explorer but this only happens in Internet Explorer 9 version.
The problem is simple, the title does not show what I put inside my  tags.
And the title that is show is the hostname of the URL I am currently browsing.

> The situation:
>       `my code <title>My Site</title>`
>
> ```
> the title must be "My Site" browsing http://localhost/mysite
> but IE9 shows "localhost" browsing http://localhost/mysite
> ```

Was someone already encountered this kind of problem? I only experience this in IE9 and not on its lower versions. On other browsers this works fine. What's the problem?

**NOTE**: I have already a ton of codes in my page but it doesn't do anything about the  element. I only use jquery as my client-side script and yii as my php framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii Framework try to add title something like this -

```
<title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
```

Check the link for further reference [Link](http://www.techportal.co.za/yii-framework/367-how-to-set-the-page-title-in-yii-framework-11x)

**UPDATE**

Check cufon font, as this may sometimes cause problem.

Comment: that is the one already written in my codes.. exactly like that

Comment: Do you have some cufon font on it? try validator http://validator.w3.org/ may be something broken

Comment: what is cufon font? how can i install it?

Comment: Its a font script, that may sometimes cause some problem, better to check the site with validator so that you have a little clearer picture if something is broken and helpful to fix the issue

Comment: ok i already saw the problem.. yeah you're right with the cufon font... please put this solution as your answer.. i gonna give you a accepted answer for this one